# How to sum a row based on the total group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2012

Im facing an issue whereby how to sum the % for each of column based on group in SSRS by using expression. Refer my use case below

I have one outcome which all the product with a percentage result. Refer to my screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B57J1.png)

Below are my SSRS template.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmZAc.png)

How we get percentage result. Example: Product PG is based on 13(based on total PG) divide 51(total Inv)

Issue: I want to sum each of percentage result for all the item Example 25% + 41% + 4% and etc to populate under excel column V6.

Therefore i need some ideal how to write in SSRS expression or it only can done via query.

Seek for any ideal how can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below since you have use static columns:
=(Sum(TotalTintCash)/Sum(TotalInv)+Sum(TotalTintFOC)/Sum(TotalInv))

And then, you can provide number formatting to percentage

Comment: If is static column then yes, your way is workable but the product for BK front grill, DVR and etc is dynamic column....i tried to SUM() based on the product column then yes but if SUM() under Score column then it have repeating figure insert because one person can sell more than one item

Comment: Then, (Sum(TotalTintCash)/Sum(TotalInv)+Sum(TotalTintFOC)/Sum(TotalInv) + Sum(ColUsedForDynamicCol)/Sum(TotalInv) ) - Will work.